# How do I delete an ERM InstanceGroupConfig via the Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-emr

we have a jar that runs on Jenkins to create and delete our EMR stacks based on some json files. The delete will fail because of an InstanceGroupConfig resource. I'm not an AWS guru and though I've tried to find whether/where these resources are kept (like autoscaling groups and launch configuration resources for EC2 can be deleted), I've been unsuccessful.

I've found that if I wait for the Jenkins job to fail, it will delete all resources except the InstanceGroupConfig. I can then go into the CloudFormation dashboard and tell it to delete the stack but retain this problematic resource. I'm unsure if I need to do cleanup, or where to find this resource if so.

I can also manually delete the stack directly from CloudFormation, so long as I tell it to retain that resource.

We would like for our Jenkins jobs to be able to seamlessly delete our EMR stacks without issue.

I've looked through the documentation and It's unclear to me how to delete this resource via the jar. I've tried to get it to just retain the resource by default by setting

`"DeletionPolicy": "Retain",`

But this appears to not have made a difference.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that the currently failing Jenkins job is using our old template that doesn't have the retention deletion policy. So I may end up closing this question in shame shortly.

Comment: Yeah, turns out using the "DeletionPolicy": "Retain" was the ticket. Maybe someone will find this helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem did turn out to be that the existing stack I was trying to delete so I could redeploy and test deletion had our old template and so was not skipping the InstanceGroupConfig resource. Once Jenkins finished failing, we were able to manually delete that stack, redeploy with the new template and verify that using the "`DeletionPolicy": "Retain"` setting on the InstanceGroupConfig in the template made the difference. Our Jenkins jobs to delete EMR stacks are now running smoothly.

A real "duh" moment"